# read a text file and extract the tab and space delineated parts

Tags: python

I have a text file that has this format as follows:

```
1   1089874  108992  PCCW's chief operating officer.    Current Chief Operating Officer Mike.
1   3019446 3019327 The world's two largest.    late summer sales frenzy caused more of an industry backlash than expected.
```

For making it clear there is one label(1)+separated by tab+id1(1089874)+separated by space+id2(1089925)+separated by space+text1+separated by tab+text2

I would like to read the text file and extract `label`, `text1` and `text2` in different lists in python. How can I do that?Thank you

Comment: Hi @GoliA, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have each line in a variable `line`, just do:

```
cols = line.split() # Splits by any white space
label = cols[0]
text1 = cols[1]
text2 = ' '.join(cols[2:])
```

Or, re-reading your requirements, I think you actually want:

```
cols = line.split('\t')
label = cols[0]
text1 = ' '.join(cols[1].split()[2:])
text2 = cols[2]
```

Comment: are you missing some `.join`s there? :)

Comment: Thank you! other than the third line, the rest works.